# prettier command not working even though prettier is in devDependancies

Tags: node.js, npm, prettier, nvm, npx

In my package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
   ...
   "prettier": "^2.8.4",
   ...
}
```

I run `npm i`.

Then:

```
$ prettier 
bash: prettier: command not found
```

```
$ npx prettier -v

/var/folders/q6/npwl_7xj4wg91lg06f8pnnfh0000gn/T/npx-b98a4fce.sh: line 1: prettier: command not found
```

Not sure if this- `/var/folders/q6/npwl_7xj4wg91lg06f8pnnfh0000gn/T/npx-b98a4fce.sh`- is normal.

I am using nvm, using node `v16.17.1` and npm `v8.15.0`

Any ideas why this is happening or how to debug it?

EDIT: `prettier` worked after I `npm install -g prettier` to install prettier globally. But shouldn't it work without this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bunch of things, I noticed it only affected this one folder. So what finally worked was simply cloning the repo again into a different folder.

Answer (score 3):

Installing a module that includes a CLI program like prettier, nodemon, etc., will place the program in `node_modules/.bin`. Your terminal shell does not know to look in this folder when you run a command. Type `echo $PATH` in your terminal to see a list of the folders that are checked when you run a command. You'll see that running `prettier` will be looking in places like `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc., but definitely not `/var/folders/q6/npwl_7xj4wg91lg06f8pnnfh0000gn/T/node_modules`.

This is why `npx` is often used; from their docs:

> Executes  either from a local node_modules/.bin, or from a central cache, installing any packages needed in order for  to run.

You could also run it via `./node_modules/.bin/prettier`, or you could install it globally, as you ultimately did, which will put it in a place that is part of your `$PATH`.